# I am trying to run a crontab but I am not getting the correct response?

Tags: cron

This is running on a Raspberry pi 3b
I'm trying to run:

```
*/1 * * * *   date > /dev/tty1
```

I get:

```
 service cron status

● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-02-23 01:31:53 EST; 32min ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
 Main PID: 396 (cron)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 1170)
   Memory: 1.5M
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           └─396 /usr/sbin/cron -f

Feb 23 02:02:01 pi002 CRON[2185]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Feb 23 02:02:01 pi002 CRON[2185]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user pi

Feb 23 02:02:01 pi002 CRON[2186]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user pi

Feb 23 02:03:01 pi002 CRON[2221]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)

Feb 23 02:03:01 pi002 CRON[2222]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)

Feb 23 02:03:01 pi002 CRON[2229]: (pi) CMD (echo "2 minutes later...")

Feb 23 02:03:01 pi002 CRON[2230]: (pi) CMD (date > /dev/tty1)

Feb 23 02:03:01 pi002 CRON[2221]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Feb 23 02:03:01 pi002 CRON[2221]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user pi

Feb 23 02:03:01 pi002 CRON[2222]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user pi
```

Comment: You haven't provided your OS/release details.

Comment: Only thing I see: always use absolute paths on cron.

Comment: Are pi logged in on tty1?

Comment: User `pi` may not have write permission to `/dev/tty1`.